# Return error while specifing a field to partition in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

If I specify 'dt' to be a partition, then error comes that "FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask". 
here is my code with partition:

```
   create EXTERNAL table novaya.user_goods_behaviour 
(  member_srl           string,  
   productid            string ,   
   buy_amt              bigint,  
   return_amt           bigint, 
   cart_cnt             bigint,  
   view_cnt             bigint,  
   search_click_cnt     bigint , 
   brand                string , 
   mng_catecode1        int ,
   mng_cate1            string , 
   mng_catecode2        int ,
   mng_cate2            string , 
   mng_catecode3        int ,
   mng_cate3            string  ,
   mng_catecode4        int ,
   mng_cate4            string ) partitioned by (dt string) 
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS parquet;

insert overwrite table novaya.user_goods_behaviour PARTITION (dt)
select * from ...;
```

however, when I don't use the partition, it is OK.

```
create EXTERNAL table novaya.user_goods_behaviour 
(  member_srl           string,  
   productid            string ,
    dt                   string,
   buy_amt              bigint,  
   return_amt           bigint, 
   cart_cnt             bigint,  
   view_cnt             bigint,  
   search_click_cnt     bigint , 
   brand                string , 
   mng_catecode1        int ,
   mng_cate1            string , 
   mng_catecode2        int ,
   mng_cate2            string , 
   mng_catecode3        int ,
   mng_cate3            string  ,
   mng_catecode4        int ,
   mng_cate4            string )  
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS parquet;



 insert overwrite table novaya.user_goods_behaviour select * from ...;
```

So I want to know what's wrong with this and how to fix it.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition fields should be last in the select projection list.

i.e. Since `dt` is the partition column, it should be last. You are using `*` operator, so not sure if `dt` is last or not.

Try following query:

```
insert overwrite table novaya.user_goods_behaviour PARTITION (dt)
Select `(dt)?+.+`, st from ....;
```

Comment: I changed the field selecting order and put the dt at last. And it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with columns name :

```
insert overwrite table novaya.user_goods_behaviour PARTITION (dt)
select column1,column2.... from ...
```

That is not solve your problem and then you can try to run this query before inserting query :

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```